# switching from real mode to protected mode

Tags: x86, bootloader, xv6

I was studying the code of the xv6 boot loader, where the first few lines of the code change the x86 mode from real to protected mode. For this switching of mode, we must enable the PE bit in CR0 and then perform a long jump to actually load the CS.
But for performing the long jump the CS is pointing to the null entry (initial value loaded by BIOS). this will require fetching ljmp from the memory, but according to the intel x86 manual, any memory access with the null selector should result in an exception.

```
  lgdt    gdtdesc    
  movl    %cr0, %eax
  orl     $CR0_PE, %eax 
  movl    %eax, %cr0
  movl gdtdesc, %eax
  ljmp    $(SEG_KCODE<<3)
```

Now my question is why the fetching of the ljmp does not cause an exception?

Comment: Setting CR0.PE doesn't make the CPU re-evaluate its current segment stuff; the permissions and base are still whatever they were before.  The old value of CS was set in real mode, setting base = `cs<<4` and `limit = 64k`, default address and operand-size = 16, etc.

Comment: does this mean that only ljmp instruction can activate the protected mode ?

Comment: No, the processor is in protected mode as soon as you set PE.  It is in 16-bit protected mode.

Comment: Then when does it switch to 32 bit?